# Notification API always returning denied Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am working on a program and need to make notifications. I am using the Notification API and I am reading the docs here...

[Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API)

But I cannot seem to get the API to work. I made a file, and a function called notify() first I try asking for permission

My code....

```
Notification.requestPermission().then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

I did just as the API told me but it always returns denied. Why is this? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Also I am not working on Mobile.

Comment: I am working on Desktop

Comment: Re the comments above: To improve the question by adding details, use the "edit" link, not comments.

Comment: Do you get the confirmation dialog from Chrome? If I put that code in a page and load it, I get the dialog; and if I click "Allow", I see "granted" as the result.

Comment: No. I get nothing but denied.

Comment: How are you running the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you're running your page from a `file://` URL, e.g., by double-clicking it in a file explorer or similar. Notification permission is silently denied from `file://` URLs.

Run it from a web server (can be a local web server), and Chrome will pop up the confirmation dialog, which you can then respond to.

I can confirm that your code works ("granted") when run from a real web page (`http://`), and not ("denied") when run from a file (`file://`):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ah I see. Let me go try on my server. Will it be able to work on a Chrome extension as well?

Comment: I got it working on my server. I thank you very much.

Comment: @J.Doedoedoedoe: Extensions have a different mechanism for requesting permissions; more: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktop_notifications

Comment: My local server is on a local VM using domain name like domail.local/ so this is always returning denies... :(

Comment: Please use chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure to define local origin as secure

Comment: @Loenix - It's not the domain name, it's the protocol (scheme). Sounds like you're using `http`, not `https`. You can create a self-signed SSL cert and have your domain.local server provide HTTPS instead so you don't have to add that domain to that Chrome setting.

Comment: I don't think self signed certificate are recognized as secure by chrome...